# CustomScrollView object does not update with input from StatefulBuilder

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have a CustomScrollView that gets updated upon user input. The actual items in the ListView are in a `SliverChildBuilderDelegate` inside the  CustomScrollView which is inside the `body` of the Scaffold object (see the code below). If a user adds an item in the form that is inside the StatefulBuilder which is inside a `showDialog` object, the item does not get added to the `planets` list which thus does not update the ListView. I think the problem is caused by the `StatefulBuilder` which I need to update my `DropdownButton`. 
My code:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: HomePage(),
  ));
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class Planet {
  final String id;
  final String name;
  final String location;
  final String distance;
  final String gravity;
  final String image;

  const Planet({this.id, this.name, this.location, this.distance, this.gravity, this.image});
}

class Coin {
  int id;
  String name;

  Coin(this.id, this.name);

  static List<Coin> getCoins() {
    return <Coin>[
      Coin(1, 'coin1'),
      Coin(2, 'coin2'),
      Coin(3, 'coin3'),
      Coin(4, 'coin4'),
      Coin(5, 'coin5'),
    ];
  }
}

class MenuItem {
  String title;
  String icon;
  Color color;
  Function func;
  MenuItem(this.title, this.icon, this.color, this.func);
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {

  List<Coin> _coins = Coin.getCoins();
  List<DropdownMenuItem<Coin>> _dropdownMenuItems;
  Coin _selectedCoin;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _dropdownMenuItems = buildDropdownMenuItems(_coins);
    _selectedCoin = _dropdownMenuItems[0].value;
    super.initState();

    _menuItems = createMenuItems();
    _selectedMenuItem = _menuItems.first;
  }

  MenuItem _selectedMenuItem;
  List<MenuItem> _menuItems;
  List<Widget> _menuOptionWidgets = [];

  List<MenuItem> createMenuItems() {
    final menuItems = [
      new MenuItem("Dashboard", 'assets/images/dashboard.png', Colors.black, () => new Dashboard()),
      new MenuItem("Cows", 'assets/images/cow.png', Colors.green, () => new Cows()),
    ];

    return menuItems;
  }

  _onSelectItem(MenuItem menuItem) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedMenuItem = menuItem;
    });
    Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomePage()),
    );
    Navigator.of(context).pop(); // close side menu
  }

  List<DropdownMenuItem<Coin>> buildDropdownMenuItems(List coins) {
    List<DropdownMenuItem<Coin>> items = List();
    for (Coin coin in coins) {
      items.add(
        DropdownMenuItem(
          value: coin,
          child:
          Text(
            coin.name,
            style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 18.0,
                color: Colors.black87,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
    }
    return items;
  }

  onChangeDropdownItem(Coin selectedCoin, StateSetter setState) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedCoin = selectedCoin;
      print('${_selectedCoin.name}');
    });
  }

  final coinController = TextEditingController();
  final amountController = TextEditingController();
  final purposeController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // Clean up the controller when the widget is disposed.
    coinController.dispose();
    amountController.dispose();
    purposeController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  List<Planet> planets = [];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    _menuOptionWidgets = [];
    DateTime now = DateTime.now();
    String formattedDate = DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd kk:mm').format(now);

    for (var menuItem in _menuItems) {
      _menuOptionWidgets.add(new Container(
          decoration: new BoxDecoration(
              color: menuItem == _selectedMenuItem
                  ? Colors.grey[200]
                  : Colors.white),
          child: new ListTile(
              leading: new Image.asset(menuItem.icon),
              onTap: () => _onSelectItem(menuItem),
              title: Text(
                menuItem.title,
                style: new TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 20.0,
                    color: menuItem.color,
                    fontWeight: menuItem == _selectedMenuItem
                        ? FontWeight.bold
                        : FontWeight.w300),
              ))));


      _menuOptionWidgets.add(
        new SizedBox(
          child: new Center(
            child: new Container(
              margin: new EdgeInsetsDirectional.only(start: 20.0, end: 20.0),
              height: 0.3,
              color: Colors.grey,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
    }

    double screenHeight;
    screenHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Dashboard'),
        backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(53, 73, 94, 0.9),
        elevation: 0.0,
//        leading: Container(),
      ),
      drawer: new Drawer(
        child: new ListView(
          children: <Widget>[
            new Container(
                child: new ListTile(
                    leading: new CircleAvatar(
                      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
                      radius: 40.0,
                      child: Text(
                        "L",style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.orange,
                          fontSize: 46.0),
                      ),
                    ),
                    title: Text("Welcome",style: TextStyle(fontSize: 46.0),)
                ),
                margin: new EdgeInsetsDirectional.only(top: 20.0),
                color: Colors.white,
                constraints: BoxConstraints(maxHeight: 90.0, minHeight: 90.0)),
            new SizedBox(
              child: new Center(
                child: new Container(
                  margin:
                  new EdgeInsetsDirectional.only(start: 10.0, end: 10.0),
                  height: 0.3,
                  color: Colors.black,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            new Container(
              color: Colors.white,
              child: new Column(children: _menuOptionWidgets),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: new Container(
        width: 120.0,
        height: 120.0,
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom:40.0),
        child: FloatingActionButton(
          child: Icon(Icons.add,size: 50.0),
          elevation: 0.0,
          onPressed: () {
            showDialog(
              context: context,
              builder: (context) {
                return StatefulBuilder(
                    builder: (BuildContext context, StateSetter setState) {
                      return Container(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                            top: screenHeight / 5,
                            bottom: screenHeight / 4
                        ),
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, right: 10),
                        child: Card(
                          color: Color.fromRGBO(53, 73, 94, 0.9),
                          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                          ),
                          elevation: 8,
                          child: Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
                            child: Column(
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Align(
                                  alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                                  child: Text(
                                      "Create",
                                      style: Style.headerTextStyle
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Divider(
                                    color: Colors.white
                                ),
                                SizedBox(
                                  height: 15,
                                ),
                                DropdownButton(
                                  value: _selectedCoin,
                                  items: _dropdownMenuItems,
                                  onChanged: (selectedCoin) {
                                    setState(() {
                                      _selectedCoin = selectedCoin;
                                      print('${_selectedCoin.name}');
                                    });
                                  }, //onChangeDropdownItem(_selectedCoin, setState),
                                ),
                                SizedBox(
                                  height: 15,
                                ),
                                TextFormField(
                                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                                      labelText: "Amount",
                                      hasFloatingPlaceholder: true,
                                      labelStyle: Style.commonTextStyle
                                  ),
                                  controller: amountController,
                                ),
                                SizedBox(
                                  height: 20,
                                ),
                                TextFormField(
                                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                                      labelText: "What is it for?",
                                      hasFloatingPlaceholder: true,
                                      labelStyle: Style.commonTextStyle
                                  ),
                                  controller: purposeController,
                                ),
                                SizedBox(
                                  height: 20,
                                ),
                                Row(
                                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment
                                      .spaceEvenly,
                                  children: <Widget>[
                                    Expanded(
                                      child: Container(),
                                    ),
                                    ButtonTheme(
                                      minWidth: 150.0,
                                      child: RaisedButton(
                                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                        child: Text('Share',
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                              fontSize: 24,
                                              color: Colors.black87,
                                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
                                                18.0)
                                        ),
                                        color: Colors.white,
                                        splashColor: Colors.blueGrey,
                                        onPressed: () {
                                          setState(() {
                                            planets.add(Planet(
                                              id: '1',
                                              // TODO need to adjust this
                                              name: purposeController.text,
                                              location: '€' + amountController.text,
                                              distance: formattedDate,
                                              gravity: 'test',
                                              image: _setImage(), // TODO might have to pass _selectedCoin as parameter
                                            )
                                            );
                                          });
                                          Navigator.pop(context);
                                        },
                                      ),
                                    ),

                                  ],
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      );
                    }
                );
              },
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          new Expanded(
            child: new Container(
              color: Color.fromRGBO(53, 73, 94, 0.9),
              child: new CustomScrollView(
                scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                slivers: <Widget>[
                  new SliverPadding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 0.0),
                    sliver: new SliverFixedExtentList(
                      itemExtent: 152.0,
                      delegate: new SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                            (context, index) => new PlanetRow(planets[index]),
                        childCount: planets.length,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The expected result is that the object from user input gets added to the `planets` list. The `Sliver` object then gets the updated `planets` list which shows the user input in a *Planet Card*. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Add `var theState = this` as the first line in `_HomePageState#build()` and then inside `DropdownButton#onChanged` use `theState.setState(...)`. If this works, you should be able to understand what the problem in your code is.

Comment: What do you mean with `var theState = this`? I assume you mean `Widget build(BuildContext context)` with `_HomePageState#build()` right?

Comment: As I said, ADD `var theState = this;` as the first line INSIDE `_HomePageState#build()` method. So, yes it would obviously be the line after `Widget.build(BuildContext context)`.

Comment: Great! I added `theState.setState()` to `onPressed: ()`, not the `DropdownButton` object. This worked. Could you explain how this solves my problem or post a link? Moreover, should I post the answer myself or will you?